# Terraform with Azure - How to create Storage Account?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-storage-account

After fighting for one day with Terraform, I am here crying for help.

```
Terraform v0.11.11
+ provider.azurerm v1.20.0
```

I am trying to create a new resource group and a storage account from scratch. It looks like it is possible to create a resource group without a storage account:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg1" {
  name     = "myResourceGroup"
  location = "West Europe"
}
```

the resource group gets created and no storage account exist at the moment. So at this point I am happy. I execute *destroy* and start from scratch again.

Now, in the code, after the resource group is created, I would like to create a storage account, since other resources later will need to reference it. The only reference that *azurerm_storage_account* needs is the reference to the resource group.

info about azurerm_storage_account
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/storage_account.html

The code looks like this now:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg1" {
  name     = "myResourceGroup"
  location = "West Europe"
}

data "azurerm_storage_account" "stacc1" {
  name                     = "mystorageaccount"
  resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name}"
}
```

I run the *plan* command and get the following output:

```
$ terraform plan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create
 <= read (data resources)

Terraform will perform the following actions:

 <= data.azurerm_storage_account.stacc1
      id:                               <computed>
      access_tier:                      <computed>
      account_encryption_source:        <computed>
      account_kind:                     <computed>
      account_replication_type:         <computed>
      account_tier:                     <computed>
      custom_domain.#:                  <computed>
      enable_blob_encryption:           <computed>
      enable_file_encryption:           <computed>
      enable_https_traffic_only:        <computed>
      location:                         <computed>
      name:                             "mystorageaccount"
      primary_access_key:               <computed>
      primary_blob_connection_string:   <computed>
      primary_blob_endpoint:            <computed>
      primary_connection_string:        <computed>
      primary_file_endpoint:            <computed>
      primary_location:                 <computed>
      primary_queue_endpoint:           <computed>
      primary_table_endpoint:           <computed>
      resource_group_name:              "myResourceGroup"
      secondary_access_key:             <computed>
      secondary_blob_connection_string: <computed>
      secondary_blob_endpoint:          <computed>
      secondary_connection_string:      <computed>
      secondary_location:               <computed>
      secondary_queue_endpoint:         <computed>
      secondary_table_endpoint:         <computed>
      tags.%:                           <computed>

  + azurerm_resource_group.rg1
      id:                               <computed>
      location:                         "westeurope"
      name:                             "myResourceGroup"
      tags.%:                           <computed>


Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

it says that it will be looking for (not creating) the resource *data.azurerm_storage_account.stacc1*, and obviously running *apply* command will fail with the message:

> Error: Error applying plan:
>
> 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> - data.azurerm_storage_account.stacc1: data.azurerm_storage_account.stacc1: Error: Storage Account
>     "mystorageaccount" (Resource Group "myResourceGroup") was not found

because it did not find the mentioned storage account.

All this leads to my question, "How can I create a storage account with Terraform in Azure?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use resource, not data entity. That is true for all the resources. Data entity is to get resource data, not create them.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "testrg" {
  name     = "resourceGroupName"
  location = "westus"
}    

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "testsa" {
  name                     = "storageaccountname"
  resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.testrg.name}"
  location                 = "westus"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  tags {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_account.html

Comment: Thanks! of course you are right!
I think I copied it from a keyvault definition at some point and did not notice it was data and not resource.